# CSS Media queries work in Firefox but not in Chrome, suggestion needed

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, media-queries

So I'm trying to aim three different version of screen with css media queries. They differ in their heights. 900px, 1080px, and 1200px. I've tried all kind of stuff and the best that partly works for now  is this one:

```
@media (height: 900px) {
    .body-base{
        height:78%;
    }
}

@media (height: 1080px) {
    .body-base{
        height:82%;
    }
}

@media (height: 1200px) {
    .body-base{
        height:85%;
    }
}
```

I'm saying partly working because upper code only works in Firefox but not in Chrome or Opera for example... What am I doing wrong? And what is the right way that this kind of css settings works across all browsers?

Comment: @jumpingcode: All these media queries are valid, and Firefox should correctly apply these styles when the viewport is exactly 900px, 1080px and 1200px tall respectively. If Chrome is ignoring the media queries completely then it's incorrect. The spec doesn't say the min/max prefixes are required. But you're right, if OP is trying to target *ranges* of viewport heights then they need the min/max prefixes.

Comment: when I add max- prefix, only 900 px query does not works, it skips to 1200 px property

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the Mozilla docs here: [Mozilla link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#height) which confirms my suspicions in the comments. Here the `height` must be prefixed by either a `min` or `max`, i.e. `min-height` in your example. Thanks to BoltClock I've just seen that it isn't in fact required to be prefixed but currently I'm assuming your media queries are targeting that exact height. E.g. `media (height:900px)` would only be used when the browser is ***exactly*** 900px in height.

However, I'm not sure why it's working in Firefox and not Chrome. It should probably be ignored by both as how can the browser make the assumption of whether you mean `min-height` or `max-height` but instead only Chrome is ignoring it.

### Solution

Decide whether you want `min-height` or `max-height`. In the example I will use `min-height` as a mobile-first approach:

```
@media (min-height: 900px) {    
    .body-base{
        height:78%;
    }
}

@media (min-height: 1080px) {    
    .body-base{
        height:82%;
    }    
}

@media (min-height: 1200px) {    
    .body-base{
        height:85%;
    }    
}
```

Comment: "The `height` must be prefixed by either a `min` or `max`, i.e. `min-height`." Where does it say that? It says that some media features *can* have those prefixes, but it doesn't say that they *must* have them.

Comment: And why did you roll back my edit? "Mozilla", "Firefox" and "Chrome" are not "code" words unlike `min-height` and `max-height` - you're not supposed to be highlighting those with `.